# "where" + "or_where, "or_where" leaving out conditions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How would I make it so I have the conditions of:

```
$this->db->where('msgto.msgto_display', 'y');
$this->db->where('msgto.msgto_unread', 'y');
```

But then have:

```
$this->db->where('msgto.msgto_recipient', $userid);
$this->db->or_where('msgto.msgto_recipient', 4);
```

At the moment its fine apart from when it reads the "or_where" it leaves out above "conditions" so the results to recipient 4 dont have the `('msgto.msgto_display', 'y')` and `('msgto.msgto_unread', 'y')`flagged.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I can't believe that human being can produce such an ugly junk out of neat wonderful SQL.

Comment: I'm sure binary would be a lot easier to read :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using CodeIgniters $this->db->where_in() function:

```
$this->db->where_in('msgto.msgto_recipient', array($userid, 4));
```

I was having a similar problem where I needed to have the condition be true with multiple possible values, and this did the trick.

My situation was I wanted to find content whose status was in a published or locked state.

```
$this->db->where_in('status', array('published','locked'));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm. Merry Christmas to you and your family!

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help. Merry Christmas to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure CodeIgniter's query builder is powerful enough to handle that case, based on its documentation. You may need to do your query on recipient first, and then manually filter the results.

Comment: Would that not put an unnecessary amount of work to the server? I know it wouldn't be much, but wouldn't it be better in the long run to filter results in your query than * then filtering them out after the query's run?

Comment: @Elgoog: "Give me that box of widgets so I can look for the ones I want" -vs- "Go through that box of widgets and give me any widget that's red, and any that are green AND have a sticker on them"